# Tagged with tag untagged

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

This [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3116/scientific-accuracy-alien-communication-ideas) has been closed as a duplicate, and I therefore cannot edit the tags. Since this is tagged as [untagged](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged), this tag appears in the list of tags when people are considering what tags to apply to their questions. As it would never be appropriate to use this tag, I recommend that the question be edited to show a valid tag, so that untagged can be removed and will no longer appear as a misleading example for new users.

How can this tag be removed now that the question is closed as duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Monica beat me to it by a minute. :) This was an unintended side effect of a migration plus merge, but the question in question now has the same tags on both sides of the merge so this should no longer be an issue.

The duplicate question came from the [Amateur Radio SE](https://ham.stackexchange.com/) (it has been posted on several sites, and deemed off topic everywhere except on Worldbuilding), where it was tagged, but the sites had no tags in common. Thus, the question had its tags removed and replaced with [untagged] as part of the migration process. When I merged the questions, I didn't consider the tags on the migrated question, and it was left with the [untagged] tag.

Comment: Heh, and you beat me to actually getting the answer up here by a minute. :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio On the other hand, your answer was more thorough. Friends? ;)

Comment: Friends!  That was never in doubt. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't the closure; it was probably the merge.  Your link actually took me to the new (destination) question, which has tags, so I was initially confused.  When I searched for the [untagged](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag I found it.

I have edited the tags of that question to match those of the one it was merged into.  This should remove the "untagged" tag in about a day.

Two "oh by the ways":

- You can't remove the last tag from a question.  If you were trying to delete "untagged" without replacing it with something, that would have failed no matter the state of the question.
- Questions that are migrated here from other sites can come in as untagged, so we may see this pop up again.  If you ever see that tag and can help, please do jump in (as you tried to do here).  Thanks.

Comment: It was a migration from [ham.se], where it was tagged. Since none of those tags existed on [worldbuilding.se], it was retagged to only [untagged]. Like I said, unintended side effect. :)

Comment: A migration from *AR*?  Cool!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I think the link must have changed its behaviour while these changes were going on - I tested it after posting this meta question and it took me to the untagged question, but now it's all merged...

Comment: Caching.  When in doubt, always blame caching. :-)